# Spring : @Autowired not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, autowired, spring-rabbit

**It is not a duplicate question. Please go through this question**I am using Spring 4.0.2. It is web based application where I am using RabbitMQ Server too for process multiple jobs at a time. I have used @Autowired object in controller services and Daos It is working fine.

But When we used bean inside RabbitMQ Listeners. It gives Null. have a look.

here is Project Tree

[image: Project Tree]

Here is TransformerClient class snapshot.

```
@Component
public class TransformerClient {

     @Value("${TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL}")
     private String TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL;

     public TransformerClient() {
          super();
          logger.info("Instantiated " + getClass());
     }

     public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TransformerClient.class);
....
}
```

Here is TCListener Class.

This class is actually RabbitMq listener. When any job pushed in queue, It is responsible to execute this process respectively. Automatically onMessage() function will execute.

```
public class TCListener implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TCListener.class);

    @Autowired
    TransformerClient transformerClient;

    public TCListener() {
           super();
          logger.info("Instantiated " + getClass());
    }

    @override
    public void onMessage(Message message){
         if(transformerClient !=null)
               logger.info("Not null");
         else
               logger.info("null");
   }
}
```

Servlet Config File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->
    <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:amqp.properties"/> -->
    <context:property-placeholder
    system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT" location="classpath:*.properties" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <!-- enable anno support -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- anno based req mapping controller -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="in.xxxx.broker" />
   .....
</beans:beans>
```

When I run this project, Beans are getting created and instantiated. Console Results.

[image: Console]

> What Solutions I have tried out :
>
> > 1) Clean and Build Project from command prompt - mvn -X clean install
> >
> > 2) Check Component Scan - < context:component-scan base-package="in.xxxx.broker" />
> >
> > 3) using applicationContext.getBean("idOfBean")
> >
> > 4) changed variable name -> TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL  to transUrl
> >
> > 5) Changed Workspace
> >
> > 6) tried on newly installed Eclipse

But Still It is getting null.

> Update : 1

In Servlet-context.xml File, I tried to create Bean and initialize value of TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL by taking values from properties file as well as I have remove @component and @Value annotations from TransFormerClient class.

```
<bean id="transformerClient" class="in.cdac.broker.client.TransformerClient">
        <property name="TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL" value="${TRANSFORMER_COMPONENT_URL}"/>  
</bean>
```

Here autowiring works properly. I did get the reason.

Comment: Basically it cannot be `null` if it would be `null` you would get an exception stating that the dependency could be found (if it is a spring managed bean and you  have setup annotation based injection correctly). next your beans are instantiated in different contexts and your `TCListener` that requires the `TransformerClient` is defined in the root context which cannot access beans loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Hence even when you annotation scanning was setup correctly it would fail.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, As Spring beans never be null. I am feeling TCListener is not creating under Spring scope. If I want to make TCListener Spring Bean How can I make it?

Comment: If it was it would fail as it cannot access the bean it needs. I would say your configuration and setup is flawed to start with.

Comment: Your `TCListener` is defined by the root context (loaded by the`ContextLoaderListener` is guess this doesn't have a `<context:component-scan />` or `<context:annotation-config />` Make sure both the client and listener are instantiated by the root context so they can see each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need integrate RabbitMQ and spring. You can find here, how do it:

You can write something like this:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@EnableRabbit //need for activation of handler for annotation @RabbitListener
@Component
public class TCListener {
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TCListener.class);

    @Autowired
    TransformerClient transformerClient;

    @RabbitListener(containerFactory="myRabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues="myQueue")
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        if(transformerClient !=null){
               logger.info("Not null");
        }else{
               logger.info("null");
        }
    }
}
```

Also need add to spring config:

```
 <rabbit:annotation-driven container-factory="myRabbitListenerContainerFactory"/>

     <bean id="myRabbitListenerContainerFactory"  class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
           // factory settings
     </bean>
```

Also you can view next guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/